# meaning of g++ inline assembly constraints (equals vs plus, etc)

Tags: gcc, x86, inline-assembly

I have been using this little function under gcc/x86 to do fast byte-swapping of int16_t's:

```
static inline int16_t MySwapInt16t(int16_t val)
{
   __asm__ ("xchgb %b0, %h0" : "=Q" (val) : "0" (val));
   return val;
}
```

... today while browsing through someone else's code on line, I saw he had a similar function that looks like this:

```
static inline int16_t HisSwapInt16t(int16_t val)
{
   __asm__ ("xchgb %h0, %b0" : "+Q" (val));
   return val;
}
```

The differences between my function and his function (AFAICT) are:

1. He specifies "+Q" instead of "=Q"
2. The positions of %h0 and %b0 are exchanged
3. He has no : "0" (val) clause at the end of his function

As far as I can tell, both implementations seem to work correctly, but inline assembly is a bit of a black art to me, so can someone knowledgable explain:

1. What is the significance of the three differences listed above?
2. Is one of the two implementations better or faster than the other, or will they both perform equivalently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> He specifies "+Q" instead of "=Q"
>
> He has no : "0" (val) clause at the end of his function

The `+` modifier stands for a both input and output operand, therefore it's no need to add an input list, check the [CGG manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.0/gcc/Modifiers.html#Modifiers) about that.

> The positions of %h0 and %b0 are exchanged

I guess it doesn't matter since the `xchg` instruction does a content exchange between the two operands.

> Is one of the two implementations better or faster than the other, or will they both perform equivalently?

To find out the best implementation, I would compile both and check with `objdump` how the compiler wrapped these function since the core function will be the same single instruction.

Hope this help!